# How do I revert back to SDK Tools 21?

Tags: android

After updating to 21.1 I have been experiencing an issue 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$layout`

I need to revert back to SDK 20 or 21. How can I do that?

Comment: The way I would do it is by restoring the backup I created just before upgrading.

Comment: @mah I didn't create a back up. does it do it automatically?

Comment: No, it's not automatic. It's just the result of having been in your apparent position and not wanting to be in it again; consider it the voice of learned experience. You should be able to download the SDK you want from http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html.

Comment: It is weird... I mean I use SDK tools v 21.1 and ActionBarSherlock and I don't have this issue. Are you sure the problem isn't in something else?

Comment: @lomza this is what some people have people saying on this site and other when I googled that error. This problem happens on older devices only from the looks of it. I can replicate it on a android 2.2 device and also had some error reports from 3.2.2

Comment: @mah that link does not have any downloads links just release notes

Comment: My apologies. I was able to go find an older releases download page, but the newest release there is from 2009 :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11444040/115145 or http://randomsamples.info/blog/phil/android-adt-2101-javalangnoclassdeffounderror-rdimen may be the sources of your root difficulty, and in either case fixing the project would be a better long-term solution.