# ActionBarsherlock: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

First, let me say that I am aware of other threads dealing with similar issues, like this one:

[ActionBarSherlock: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$styleable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443262/actionbarsherlock-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-actionbarsherlock-rstyle)

This is a slightly different case, however. My app has been in production on the Play Store for a few months now, and I today tried to release an update. The app installs and runs perfectly on my device and on an emulator. However, as soon as I export the project to an APK, and upload that to the Play Store things go wrong. Downloading this new APK (which in theory should work perfectly), I get this "ActionBarSherlock: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$styleable" error.

I am completely puzzled. For a start, this app has been working perfectly and my latest updates had nothing to do with ABS in any way. For another thing, the app works perfectly when I install and run it through Eclipse. The process of making an APK out of a working project seems to generate the error.

As this app has been a moderate (and growing) success on the Play Store, the fact that the latest update breaks it is a serious cause for concern on my part. Any advice/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you changed in the new update?

Comment: OK, the problem has been "resolved" by re-starting my laptop (and obviously restarting Eclipse) and re-creating the APK file. No code changes were done, but now the problem has gone away.